# I'm getting error Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

I'm installing jwt-auth package.I run this command

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

There is composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
```

And there is app.php file

```
  'providers' => [
              ........
        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,

    ],
   'aliases' => [
              ........
        'JWTAuth' =>Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
        'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
    ],
```

When is I run this command.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```

getting error.

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: Probably because this file doesn't exists https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/tree/1.0.0/src/Providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably reading old docs or watching some tutorial video for old version.

It should be:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

Docs: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

Comment: Even after following the new docs, removing everything jwt-auth related in config/app.php, and getting everything working on my local environment, I had issues deploying to my test environment. The key for me was to delete this file: .../bootstrap/cache/config.php.